# why does \draw not work in the axis environment in the metropolis theme?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgfplots, beamer-metropolis

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usetheme{metropolis}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[xmin=0,
    xmax=1,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1]
 \draw (0,0)--(.2,0.1);
 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

There seems to be a problem with the metropolis theme. The above produces no line just a blank box. If you comment out the `metropolis` theme, the result displays fine. Any idea why?

(for the record: Xelatex is used to combilde both).

There seem to be issues with the coordinates, because
`\node at (0.5,0.5) {node};` produces a node at the origin.

But how come this only shows up once the metropolis theme s activated?

Am I missing something important?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking over the code, the theme is forcing `compat=1.9` when `pgfplots` is loaded. That's an *old* setting, so you need to disable it with

```latex
\AtBeginDocument{\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}}
```

which restores normal service.

Comment: Thanks. That was a quick fix. A bit embarassing that I didn't notice that....

Comment: @johaschn It's not really that obvious